# How to define sister predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

"Using the predicates `parent(X,Y)`, `male(X)`, and `female(X)`, write a
Prolog predicate that defines `sister(X,Y)`."

I am trying to teach myself how to use Prolog for giggles, and the lesson I am using has this as one of the assignments, I do not even know where to begin with this.

Comment: It won't help you much getting the answer from us

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that sister(X,Y) means: X is a sister of Y (so only X must be female).
Assuming that parent(X,Y) means: X is a parent of Y.

```
sister(X,Y) :-
    female(X),
    parent(Z,Y),
    parent(Z,X),
    X \= Y.
```

Here's a great online resource to learning Prolog: http://www.learnprolognow.org/

Comment: Should it be female(X)? Reading the clauses 'X is sister of Y' which follows the same form of parent(X,Y) meaning 'X is the parent of Y'.

Comment: I agree its not clear from the question, but general prolog style would suggest that is how to read the proposition. It is how you interpreted parent(X,Y) after all.